# react dropdown menu for Link_To not loading home page as expected

Tags: reactjs, routes, menu

I created a react page where there is a navbar at the top and the select page is loaded under the navbar.   The navbar has a menu button. When the menu button is pressed a menu list appears and you can select different pages.  The home page Mcd should be loaded by default when the page is initially loaded.   This was based on a tutorial and worked fine when running npm start, but when I installed the page under a Tomcat server the NoPage 404 as loaded vs. the expected Mcd page.  For some reason the Mcd was not loaded.  If I press the button I can load any of the pages fine.  I tried changing the dropdown menu to set the select attribute on the current page, but again I got   "*" default page 404.  Currently I am doing a workaround and set the "*" from NoPage to Mcd.   Does anyone see what is wrong with this code?

App.js

```
/*
This class is to create a navigation bar at the top of the web page.
The selected action will then be loaded in the bottom half of the web page.
*/

import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import {Navbar, NavLayout} from "../nav/Navbar";
// This will only load the pages as needed.  Loading will be done only 1 time per page.
const Mcd = lazy(() => import ("../mcd/Mcd"));
const LocationTool = lazy(() => import ("../location/LocationTool"));
// const NoPage = lazy(() => import ("../nav/NoPage"));

/*
This is the main entry point into the web page which is divided into two rows where
the top is the navigation bar.

The Mcd is the default page.  Add new pages by adding a new Route block.

Notes:
I am using HashRouter because on the sever the refresh button causes a 404 message if
I am using the BrowserRouter.  The noPage default being displayed
on the initial load vs. expected Mcd, so the workaround is to use the Mcd page not found.
*/
function App() {

    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <Navbar />
            <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<NavLayout />}>
                      <Route exact index element={<Mcd />} />
                        <Route exact path="location" element={<LocationTool />} />
                        <Route exact path="*" element={<Mcd />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}
```

Navbar.js

```
/*
This class will create the navigation bar and add a dropdown menu on the right side
for all the tool pages.
*/
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { orange, purple, green } from '@mui/material/colors';

/*
    Custom theme for MenuItem.
*/
const MenuItemTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[700],
    },
    background: {
      default: orange[200],
      paper: orange[200],
    },
  },
});

/*
    The is where the want page will be loaded after you select one on the dropdown menu.
*/
 const NavLayout = () => {
   return (
     <>
       <Outlet />
     </>
   )
 };

/*
    Build the navigation bar and display the connection status.
*/
function Navbar() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [navLinks, setNavLinks] = useState([]);     /* This is the list of tool pages to add to the menu. */

  /* When the page is first rendered this will go off and will will build the tool page list */
  useEffect(() => {
    const navs = [
      { name: "MC Dashboard", path: "/" },
      { name: "Location Files", path: "location" },
    ];
    setNavLinks(navs);
  }, []);

  /* when mouse moves over menu button list appears */
  const handleOpenMenu = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  /* when mouse moves off menu button list disappears */
  const handleCloseMenu = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  /* Return the source code for the navigation bar.

  To make this work, the bootstrap.mon.css and boostrap.build.min.js
  need to be added to the public/index.html.  Otherwise you will not see anything rendered.

  The menu button is based on this example:
  @see https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu-right&stacked=h
  */
    return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}></Typography>
          <Button
            aria-controls='menu'
            onClick={handleOpenMenu}
            disableRipple
            className="{classes.accountbutton}"
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary">
            Active
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <ThemeProvider theme={MenuItemTheme}>
          <Menu
            id='menu'
            onClose={handleCloseMenu}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}>
            {navLinks.map((d, i) => (
                <MenuItem key={i} onClick={handleCloseMenu}>
                  <Link to={d.path}>
                    <button className="dropdown-item" type="button">
                      {d.name}
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
          </Menu>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  );
}

export {Navbar, NavLayout};
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the route documentation and playing around with the code, I found that the problem was in the App.js Route block.  Initially I had "exact" on each Route line, but now I only have it on the first line for path="/".  The the Mcd page then loaded correctly on start up.  This is the corrected code below.

```
return (
    <HashRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<NavLayout />}>
                    <Route index element={<Mcd />} />
                    <Route path="location" element={<LocationTool />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>
    </HashRouter>
);
```